# Exclude files from Android Studio lint spell checker

Tags: android-studio, spell-checking, lint

The Android Studio lint spell checker flags hex codes that look to it like words in certain files that would be better off unchecked, such as `values/colors.xml` and `build/intermediates/dex-cache/cache.xml`.

How do I tell lint to not spell check certain folders or files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be done by using IDE scopes. In Android Studio (at least 3.4) you can configure each inspection per scope. The idea is that you create a scope that contains all files you don't want to be spellchecked, and then switch Spelling inspection off for this scope, but keep it on for everything else.

1. Add a new scope in `Settings / Appearance & Behavior / Scopes` that contains all files which you want to exclude from spell checking. For example, this pattern covers all `svg` files: `file:*.svg`. In your case it could be like `file:*/colors.xml||file:*/cache.xml`. IDE will highlight all affected files by green, so you can check if you entered correct pattern.
2. Then set up Spelling inspection, so that it is OFF for your new scope and ON everywhere else.
   [image: Spelling]

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem with `colors.xml`

I couldn't find a way to disable the check for a certain file, but I could get rid of the spellcheck on the hex codes.

Click `Analyze->Inspect Code`.
Choose `Whole Project` and click OK.

The inspection tool window will open with the results.

You should be able to see the problematic hex codes under `Spelling->typo`.
Right click any one of them and choose `Exclude`.

Did the trick for me. HTH

Comment: How to avoid having to the inspection results show the spelling errors in the first place (so I don't need to exclude them manually) is the motivation for the question.

Comment: But this would only be for some words. analyze code also includes files not related to the project.