# Ignore spelling warning in Android studio for specific files

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to ignore spellcheck warnings for specific files only in Android Studio. I have tried this out but this seems to be equivalent to SuppressLint instead of SuppressWarning. 
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html

Here's an example of something like what I want to do

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="SpellCheckingInspection" severity="typo">
        <ignore path="app/src/main/res/values/local_values.xml" />
        <ignore path="app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml" />
        <ignore path="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" />
    </issue>
</lint>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There is already a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31947638/905686

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to ignore spell check for specific files

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the lint check for comments like below;

[image]

> click the yellow lamp and go to

**"Typo:Change to..."** -> **"Edit inspection profile setting"**

> and Inspections window will open like below;

[image]

> then uncheck the **"Process comments"** option and press **OK** button.

After those steps, typo underlines and typo lint warnings will gone.

Comment: I specifically said "for specific files only." This would disable Typo for the entire workspace.

Answer (score 1):

You can

1. suppress the spell checks for an entire class
2. or even suppress all the inspections for a particular class

by running the code inspection and selecting the specific warning to be suppressed.

Here are the steps:

From the android studio menu bar, select Analyze -> Inspect Code

Once the inspection is complete, from the list of warnings under Proofreading -> Typo -> select the particular warning from a file that has to be suppressed.

On the right-side panel, select the drop-down to suppress the warning for:

1. particular class
2. particular field
3. suppress all warnings for the particular class.

Refer to the image below FYI:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding `@file:Suppress("SpellCheckingInspection")` at the top of the file helped :)

Comment: does not work for xml files

Answer (score -4):

For Android Studio, Uncheck options you want to disable under File >> Settings >> Editor >> Inspections >> Spelling >> Typo

Comment: I specifically said "for specific files only." This would disable Typo for the entire workspace.